# How to set string date in store to date textbox inside a dojo grid

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I have a date textbox inside dojo grid

```
<th data-dgrid-column="dgrid.editor({ field:'START_DATE',editorArgs{style:'width:12em;',required:true,missingMessage:'Please enter Start date'},autoSave:true}, dijit.form.DateTextBox ) "> Start Date</th>
```

But my store has string value of date, so the date is not displayed in the datetextbox, how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `get` method of the Column to achieve this

```js
function convertToDate(dateString){
    return new Date(dateString);  
}
```

```html
<th data-dgrid-column="dgrid.editor({
    field:'START_DATE', 
    editorArgs{style:'width:12em;', required:true, missingMessage:'Please enter Start date'}, 
    autoSave:true, 
    get:convertToDate }, dijit.form.DateTextBox )"> Start Date</th>
```

Comment: It has executed correctly, what is the use of formatter??